# Add accelerator ctrl+F for text search

Tags: c++, gtkmm, accelerator, text-search

I am trying to add a Ctrl+F accelerator to my gtkmm textview program. I already implemented the search function into an gtk Entry field, so the only thing I need is to get focus the find entry when Ctrl+F is pressed.

I googled and checked tutorials/reference of gtkmm (2.4, I'm working with that) but the only things I found were accelerators in context with menus and toolbars using UIManager, which I don't have in that .cc file I use (and I can't add them, cause its an existing program).

I tried to add an action with an AccelKey on a button or tried the function add_accelerator() but I wasn't able to use them properly (I am pretty new to gtkmm and there aren't enough samples - at least none I understand). Here some examples I tried:

```
  _gtkActionGroup->add(
    Gtk::Action::create("find", "Find", "search in file"),
    Gtk::AccelKey("<control>F"),
    sigc::mem_fun(this, &SrcFilesView::onGtkTxtFindAccKeyPressed));
```

I didn't know how to add this action to the button (in the toolbar) I created...

```
  _gtkAccelGroup(Gtk::AccelGroup::create()) //initialized  in the constructor of the class
 ...
  _gtkBtnFind.add_accelerator("find", _gtkAccelGroup, GDK_Find, 
    Gdk::ModifierType::CONTROL_MASK, Gtk::ACCEL_VISIBLE);
```

I tried here something, but I didn't really understand neither the parameters I needed to enter here nor how this method works - ofc it didn't work...

I'd be really happy if anyone can explain me how this things work properly and sorry for my bad english. If there are any things you need just tell me please. Thanks in advance

Greetings

edit: I looked up in the gtk sources and tried to understand the parameters of add_accelerator. Now I tried this but still doesn't work...:

```
  _gtkBtnFind.add_accelerator("clicked", _gtkAccelGroup, GDK_KEY_F /* or better GDK_KEY_f ?*/, 
    Gdk::ModifierType(GDK_CONTROL_MASK), Gtk::AccelFlags(GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE));
  _gtkBtnFind.signal_clicked().connect(
    sigc::mem_fun(this, &SrcFilesView::onGtkTxtFindAccKeyPressed));
```

**UPDATE:**

Okay I have understood most I think now, and I know why it doesn't work. The problem is that I have to add the accel_group to the window widget, but I got only a scrolled window and boxes in my program....and now I have no clue how to continue... :)

**UPDATE2:**

Alright I managed to do it without accelerators by using the "on_key_press_event" handler by checking the state and keyval parameter. Hope this helps some ppl at least ^^.

```
bool on_key_press_event(GdkEventKey* event) { /* declaration in my constructor removed */
  if(event->state == GDK_CONTROL_MASK && event->keyval == GDK_KEY_f
    || event->state == (GDK_CONTROL_MASK | GDK_LOCK_MASK) 
       && event->keyval == GDK_KEY_F) {
    _gtkEntFind.grab_focus();
  }
  return false;
}
```

I would be still interested in a solution with the accelerators if there is any ! Greetings

Comment: `event->state` is a field of bit flags. you should use bitwise operations instead of directly comparing it:
`if( (event->state & GDK_CONTROL_MASK) == GDK_CONTROL_MASK && (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_f || event->keyval == GDK_KEY_F) )`